# Add Button bottom of the ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, button, expandablelistview

I was making an app, I used this ExpandableListView in Fragment Activity. I want to add Button at the bottom of the ListView. I was trying but when I added Button, it didn't work properly, Button was added at each list header. My code is given below.

[image] This is current screenshot

[image] I want like this

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".TurbooneFragment"
    android:background="@color/gray_50">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/turboone_view">
    </ExpandableListView>


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:id="@+id/turboone_item"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:id="@+id/listturbooneheader"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

// This is my java code:

```
    public class TurbooneFragment extends Fragment {

    private TurbooneListAdapter listadapter;
    private ExpandableListView listView;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHash;

    public TurbooneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_turboone, container, false);
        listView = view.findViewById(R.id.turboone_view);
        initData();
        listadapter = new TurbooneListAdapter(this.getContext(),listDataHeader,listHash);
        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

        return view;
    }

    private void initData(){
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listHash = new HashMap<>();

        listDataHeader.add("first");
        listDataHeader.add("second");
        listDataHeader.add("third");

        List<String> first= new ArrayList<>();
        first.add("blabla");

        List<String> second= new ArrayList<>();
        second.add("bla");

        List<String> third= new ArrayList<>();
        third.add("blabla");
        third.add("blabla");

        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(0),first);
        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(1),second);
        listHash.put(listDataHeader.get(2),third);

    }

}
```

// My ListViewAdapter:

```
    public class TurbooneListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String >> listHashMap;

    public TurbooneListAdapter (Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap){
        this.context=context;
        this.listDataHeader=listDataHeader;
        this.listHashMap=listHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return listDataHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return listHashMap.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1); // i= child item, i1= group item
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String headerTitle = (String)getGroup(i);
        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_turboone,null);
        }
        TextView list1header =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listturbooneheader);
        list1header.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        list1header.setText(headerTitle);
        return view;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final String childText = (String)getChild(i,i1);
        if (view== null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_turboone,null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.turboone_item);
        txtListChild.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: At bottom of the listview or above listview but at bottom of the screen? So, the button should be visible always on the bottom of the screen or only when the listview scrolls to very bottom? Could you upload an image showing what are you expecting?

Comment: Button should be visible always on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `layout` (fragment_turboone) for the `ExpandableListView` and for each group row and child row. You have to provide a distinct layouts for each of 3 components. One layout for your `fragment` which contains the `ExpandableListView`, another for your group layout (the headers) and another for your child view (rows inside a group).

Since you are using the same layout for all components, any `View` you add in this layout is added also in the list, in the groups and in the childs. This is why you have to create separate layouts.

**Fragment**

So, your fragment layout should be as follows:
`fragment_turboone.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 tools:context=".TurbooneFragment"
 android:background="@color/gray_50">

  <Button
    android:id="+@id/buttonId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="your text"/>

  <ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/turboone_view"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttonId">
  </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Group View**

Then, you need to create another layout (XML file inside `layout` folder in resources) for your group view:
`group_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_500"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:id="@+id/listturbooneheader"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Child View**

And another layout for your child view:
`child_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:id="@+id/turboone_item"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, you have to inflate each layout correctly. The `onCreateView()` of your `TurbooneFragment`is correct since its inflating `fragment_turboone`.

In your adapter, you have to change the layout inflated for your group and child.

In your `getGroupView()` of your `TurbooneListAdapter` you have to change the line:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_turboone, null);
```

for

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_layout, null);
```

And in your `getChildView()` of your `TurbooneListAdapter` you have to change the line:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_turboone, null);
```

for

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
```

And then you should have your list working.

Comment: After I add your xml when I was builded my app for looking how it worked error occured: 'attribute 'android:alignParentBottom' not found.'

Comment: I was added but Button was shown each header and I can't expande, collapse my listview items. I can't add screenshot sorry

Comment: So, this layout is your headed layout? I don't understand if you doesn't post a screenshot

Comment: I use this TurbooneFragment.class in tabhost

Comment: I want add screenshot, but I can't

Comment: It's hard to help you without an expected image and current image

Comment: @Cavad I've edited my answer explaining all your problem and providing a solution. Please check out if it's working for you.